# Can we deploy the war file of ADF fusion application into web logic server?

Tags: deployment, war, oracle-adf, ear, weblogic-10.x

I have created a ADF fusion application deployed in Jdev. When I deploy it as war file in Integrated weblogic server - works fine. When I deployed that as war in standalone weblogic server - it gives me error 500.

In the console (startweblogic.cmd) "**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/adf/model/RegionBinding"**

So I found on internet that deploying it as EAR the whole application would solve. Yes. It indeed was solved. My application runs fine in standalone weblogic.

Can we not deploy it as war in standalone weblogic?

The war file is working fine in integrated but not in stand alone.

Why?

P.S.: I installed ADF runtime, prepared the deployment profile to deploy as a web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should make a quick research on the difference between these two types of archives *EAR* and *WAR*, then it should be clear to you.

Anyways, the fact is that you are trying to deploy a Fusion application, which includes in itself two different projects: the `ViewController` project and the `Model` one. The reason why on the standalone version it can only work if you deploy as an *EAR* is that this type of archive can contain several WARs, JARs (and other types of archives). While a *WAR* can contain only one of the projects (you can create a WAR for each, the Model and the ViewController project) and related jars. But they would be separate, so they would not have access to each-others files. I bet you've tried to deploy the ViewController.war only. This is the reason why you should deploy an .ear on the standalone version.

Instead, the integrated version, if an EAR file is deployed at the application level, and it has dependencies on a JAR file in the data model project and dependencies on a WAR file in the view-controller project. (It means, you are not deploying just the war from JDeveloper, it internally creates an EAR).

I hope this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e16272/deploy_java_ee_app.htm) would be useful.